# Keep text between 2nd dash and first flash in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a vector of strings that look like this:

```
a - bc/def_g  - A/mn/us/ww
opq - rs/ts_uf - BC/wx/yza
Abc - so/dhie7u - XYZ/En/xy/jkq - QWNE
```

I'd like to get the text after 2nd dash (-) but before first flash (/), i.e. the result should look like

```
A
BC
XYZ
```

What is the best way to do it (the vector has more than 500K rows.)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your string is defined like this:

```
string <- c("a - bc/def_g  - A/mn/us/ww", 
            "opq - rs/ts_uf - BC/wx/yza", 
            "Abc - so/dhie7u - XYZ/En/xy/jkq - QWNE")
```

Then you can use `sub`

```
> sub(".*\\-\\s+([A-Z]+)/.*", "\\1", string)
[1] "A"   "BC"  "XYZ"
```

Answer (score 1):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/ASRUGZ/2)

```
^[^-]*-[^-]*-\s*\K[^/]+
```

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `[^-]*` Match any character except `-` any number of times
- `-` Match this literally
- `[^-]*` Match any character except `-` any number of times
- `-` Match this literally
- `\s*` Match any number of whitespace characters
- `\K` Resets the starting point of the pattern. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match
- `[^/]+` Match any character except `/` one or more times

Alternatively, as suggested by [Jan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1231450/jan) in the comments below (I believe it has since been deleted) [`^(?:\[^-\]*-){2}\s*\K\[^/\]+`](https://regex101.com/r/ASRUGZ/3) may be used. It's shorter and easily scalable, but more adds steps.

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##JY3LDoIwEEX3fEXTFSDNLN3oAg0rExMTEx8UCJQCPgrYQij@fC1xMzk5M/eONEajDUHMxTkiqGBQ8iqrkeUQRAujgmnCAcJd/7FOKhhUNlYWd3uYNMzffNmGBbNKdVA2D74eLV9vd4ha0DM8X0vydDlG2HPE8kzymuteujiNU5L45D8pVT6lhziFZGU7dYB6Lt/bs@fYe5EPrOHKtVZ4xvwA)

```
x <- c("a - bc/def_g  - A/mn/us/ww", "opq - rs/ts_uf - BC/wx/yza", "Abc - so/dhie7u - XYZ/En/xy/jkq - QWNE")
m <- regexpr("^[^-]*-[^-]*-\\s*\\K[^/]+", x, perl=T)
regmatches(x, m)
```

Result: `[1] "A"   "BC"  "XYZ"`

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you so much